# Padding top disappears on the next page

Tags: html, css, page-break

Good Day,

I'm having trouble with my project. Im printing a page using printThis.js.
The problem occurs when creating a new page. The header at page 1 is normal/ok, but in succeeding pages, the padding at the top of the page disappears and the heading or thead will hit the border.

What seems to be the problem in this? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th style="height:50px;"> 
             header
         </th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <p>something here</p>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td style="height:50px;">
            footer
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    page-break-after:always !important;
}
thead{
    display: table-header-group !important;
}
tr, td{ 
    page-break-inside:avoid !important; 
    page-break-after:auto !important;
}
p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[This is the screenshot of page1 and page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lidpF.png)

Comment: It will be good if you show some codes instead of images
This can be fixed with CSS if you add code in question

Comment: Thanks you for you suggestion. I will do that

Comment: add margin-bottom: 20px;  in .page
Change px value according to your desire output

Comment: it only affected the first page.

Comment: adding some padding to <th> solved the problem. thank you for your response.

Comment: I also added padding:0 at .page

Comment: Good it works if you need further help you can open up new question